# If button enabled, then do this onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I want to show a popup on click of "add to cart button" (but only when the button is active!) so i think i can use the a div that wraps the button which change class from "disabled" to "enabled" i used jquery but it is not so important if it is jquery or pure javascipt.

I made it work on codepen, but doesn't work on my website? 
See codepen: https://codepen.io/Molin449/pen/mYXPXv

Any idea of what im doing wrong?

```js
$('.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart.variations_button.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled .single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
  $("#CartPopup").css("display", "block");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--The popup div-->
<div id="CartPopup" class="CartPopup"></div>

<!--This is the div that changes between disabled and enabled-->
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">

<!--The button where i want the onclick event (only when active)-->
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button">Tilføj til kurv</button> <a href="https://www.profiltech.dk/kurv/" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="Se kurv">Se kurv</a></div>
```

Comment: Instead of setting the class on a parent element, add the `disabled` attribute to the `button` itself. Then no events can be raised from it

Comment: I can't edit the html, as it is a wordpress site using woocommerce  as webshop, otherwise i would definitely do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

On Wordpress/Wooccommerce you need first to use explicitely `jQuery()` ready event (embedding the shortand `$`)…

Now on Woocommerce, you can use the **`disabled`** class *(as @RoryMcCrossan suggested in his comment)*, so **when your button will not have the class `disabled`**, it will be able to show the lightbow.

```js
jQuery( function($){
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
        if( ! $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) {
            $("#CartPopup").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#CartPopup{
  display:none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--The popup div-->
<div id="CartPopup" class="CartPopup"></div>

<!--This is the div that changes between disabled and enabled-->
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">

<!--The button where i want the onclick event (only when active)-->
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button">Tilføj til kurv</button> <a href="https://www.profiltech.dk/kurv/" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="Se kurv">Se kurv</button></div>
```

And will not work if your button is like:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button disabled">Tilføj til kurv</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, that partly worked! I changed the selector to only use ".single_add_to_cart_button" and then it worked perfectly! Thanks alot!